# Accessing generic member variable throws compilation error

Tags: generics, c++-cli, managed-c++

I have C++/CLI code, which looks like:

```
  interface class Type
  {

  };
  public ref class Type1 : Type
  {
  public:
    double a;
  };

  public ref class Type2 : Type
  {
  public:
    double b;
  };

  generic <typename T> where T:Type
  array<T>^ TestClass::TestFunction()
  {
    array<T>^ result = gcnew array<T>(1);
    result[0].b = 10.0;
    return result;
  }
```

`Type1` and `Type2` have nothing in common, So I haven't kept anything in `Type`to implement. Its just for generics syntax purpose, I have created `Type`.

When I try to call `TestFunction` using `Type1` or `Type2`, their members `a` & `b` are not accessible. 
Compiler says, `a` or `b` is not a member of `Type`.

Can you please tell me what wrong I am doing here?

Answer (score 3):

```
    resultBuffer[0].b = 10.0;
```

Best if you write code in a programming editor instead of an SO question box.  You are just adding confusion, this at least needs to be `result[0]->b = 10.0;`.  But surely the real problem is that it is not generic code at all.  As posted, it could only ever work if you write this as a template instead of a generic and then only ever use it with Type2 as the template argument.  That is not useful either.

.NET generics require you to constrain the type argument so it always has a `b` property so the method can always be generated at runtime for any T.  So your interface *must* look like:

```
interface class IType
{
    property double b { double get(); void set(double); };
};
```

Only the setter is actually required, I assumed you'd need the getter in practice.  How you implement the interface in the classes that inherit the interface is something you need to think about, I can't make a reasonable guess.

Comment: I got your answer but still my problem is not solved. Let me put my requirements: I have 2 structures which have nothing in common and these will be used in a generic function (as generic parameter) and will be called by C# client. Am I following right approach of using generics or I should avoid generics look for any other kind of solution like declaring separate APIs?

Comment: It sure doesn't sound like you have a shot at making it generic.